# Matlab get matrix with certain criteria

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say I have a simulation:

```
for i = 1:100;
    s1 = rand(1)*0.1+0.1;
    s2 = rand(1)*0.2+0.2;
    s3 = rand(1)*0.3+0.3;
    s4 = s1+s2*s3;
    sim_results(i,:) = [s1 s2 s3 s4];
end
```

I now want a separate matrix with the results only when `s4` matches certain criteria:

```
x = sim_results(:,4)>0.1 && sim_results(:,4)<0.4
```

(this doesn't work...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because of the way you index into `sim_results`. Moreover, you might want to look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html?refresh=true) link on logical operators, since in your case you likely want to use `&` instead of the short-circuit `&&`. That is, if you consider this expression:

```
expr1 && expr2
```

Then `expr2` won't be evaluated if `expr1` is false. The bottom line is, with the code you use you would likely get the error `Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.` since the `&&` operator only operates with scalar logical conditions, i.e. when you can summarize a condition as being either true or false, which is not the case when you compare an array or a matrix for instance.

So to come back to your question, I recommend doing either of the following:

**Solution 1: Vectorized code**

Here you don't need a loop since every operation you use can be vectorized:

```
s1 = rand(100,1)*.1+.1;
s2 = rand(100,1)*.2+.2;
s3 = rand(100,1)*.3+.3;
s4 = s1 + s2.*s3;

sim_results = [s1 s2 s3 s4];

x = find(s4 > .1 & s4 < 0.4) %// Get row indices for your condition

Result = sim_results(x,:)
```

Simple example with 5 rows ( I used the condition s4 > 0.4 & s4 < 0.4):

```
sim_results =

    0.1760    0.3303    0.4169    0.3137
    0.1584    0.3487    0.5326    0.3441
    0.1403    0.2604    0.3538    0.2324
    0.1510    0.2179    0.3328    0.2235
    0.1496    0.3652    0.5715    0.3583


x =

     1
     2
     5


Result =

    0.1760    0.3303    0.4169    0.3137
    0.1584    0.3487    0.5326    0.3441
    0.1496    0.3652    0.5715    0.3583
```

**Solution 2: Use temporary variable**

Here you can assign a variable to the 4th column of `sim_results` and apply the operators as above:

```
for i = 1:100;
    s1 = rand(1)*0.1+0.1;
    s2 = rand(1)*0.2+0.2;
    s3 = rand(1)*0.3+0.3;
    s4 = s1+s2*s3;
    sim_results(i,:) = [s1 s2 s3 s4];
end

TempVar = sim_results(:,4);
x1 = find(TempVar > .1 & TempVar < 0.4)
Result = sim_results(x1,:)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Benoit_11. I want to end up with a matrix with the corresponding columns for s1, s2 and s3 when s4>0.1 $ s4<0.4 though. How can I do that? Thanks again.